# SQL Recordset does not return any values when using parameters in VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel-2010

I'm new to this forum and also quite new to VBA and SQL so I don't know if the question describes the problem any good.
I have worked on a problem for a few days now but I can't manage to find the solution. I want to set the customer code "k_kod" from a cell in excel but it does not work. It returns nothing.
If I set "k_kod = '275'" directly in the SQL-statement it works fine. It also works fine with parameters (?) on for example "vg_kod" or "pa_datum".
I have also tried with a much simpler code string and then I managed to get it working with parameter input on "k_kod". But In that code it was no nested WHERE clause.

Is it because "k_kod" is in two "WHERE clauses"?

Here is the code:

```
Sub grunddata_salj()
Sheets("Summary").Select
Dim Conn1_res As ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd1_res As ADODB.Command
Dim Param1_res As ADODB.Parameter
Dim Param2_res As ADODB.Parameter
Dim Rs1_res As ADODB.Recordset
On Error Resume Next

Set Conn1_res = New ADODB.Connection
Conn1_res.ConnectionString = "DSN=xxx AB;uid=;pwd=;"
Conn1_res.Open

Set Rs1_res = New ADODB.Recordset
Set Cmd1_res = New ADODB.Command

Cmd1_res.ActiveConnection = Conn1_res
Cmd1_res.CommandText = "SELECT art_artnr, pa_datum, pa_pris " & _
  "FROM m.prisandring as A, m.artikel, m.kundart, m.kund " & _
  "WHERE pa_datum = " & _
    "( " & _
        "SELECT max(pa_datum), FROM m.kund, m.prisandring AS B " & _
        "WHERE a.pa_id = b.pa_id " & _
        "AND pa_datum < '2012-01-01' " & _
        "AND pa_kl_id = kund.k_id " & _
        "AND k_kod = ? " & _
    ") " & _
  "AND artikel.art_id = pa_id " & _
  "AND pa_prislista = '-3' " & _
  "AND kundart.art_id = artikel.art_id " & _
  "AND kundart.k_id = kund.k_id " & _
  "AND pa_kl_id = kund.k_id " & _
  "AND vg_kod <> '1' " & _
  "AND k_kod = ? " & _
  "GROUP BY art_artnr, pa_datum, pa_pris " & _
  "ORDER BY art_artnr"

Set Param1_res = Cmd1_res.CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput)
Param1_res.Value = "275"
Cmd1_res.Parameters.Append Param1_res
Set Param2_res = Cmd1_res.CreateParameter(, adInteger, adParamInput)
Param2_res.Value = "275"
Cmd1_res.Parameters.Append Param2_res

Set Rs1_res = Cmd1_res.Execute()
artno = Rs1_res("art_artnr")
p_date = Rs1_res("pa_datum")
p_price = Rs1_res("pa_pris")

Conn1_res.Close
Rs1_res.Close

End Sub
```

I would be really thankful for some help on this one.

Comment: Is k_kod really a string, even though it looks like a number -- "k_kod = '275'"? Because you should not be setting up a numeric parameter ( adInteger ) for a string input. Alternatively, you should not be putting quotes around a numeric input.

Comment: no, k_kod is actually nVarchar but it didn't work setting it like that in the CreateParameter. If I set it to an Integer it works in simpler queries. I have tried to set both with and without quotes, neither of it works in this case. In a simpler sql-string with just one k_kod and no nested clauses both of them works. If I monitor it it is set correct as just 275.

Comment: You are going to have to post some error messages. Using SQL Server I find I can easily enough run a query: `cmd.CommandText = "select * from table1 where anumber = (select max(anumber) from table1 where atext=?) and atext=?"
    Set param = cmd.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, Sheet1.[a1])
    cmd.Parameters.Append param
    Set param = cmd.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, Sheet1.[a1])
    cmd.Parameters.Append param`

Comment: The only error message I can get is if I hold the cursor over Rs1_res("art_artnr") the it says: "Rs1_res("art_artnr") =<Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding...

Comment: Did you test that the query runs in your database? What is your database?

Comment: I can also run the query without problem directly in excel with parameters. It seems that the parameters messes up the query when I run it through VBA and it doesn't return anything. It works if I set any other of the records as parameter. It's just k_kod that, in this case, messes it up.

Comment: Yes, I did run it directly in my database. It's Sybase, and it works fine.

Comment: When you set k_kod = '275' it works, but have you tried a text parameter and what error do you get? `Set param = cmd.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, '275')` You will need to change 10 to the correct length.

Comment: I have tried that also and the same error. Actually I have tried with a simpler query with k_kod only occuring one time set as parameter. Then it doesn't work with varchar but is does work with integer. I also doublechecked and k_kod is an nvarchar with length 10, but I have tried that also..

Comment: I am running out of ideas. Try adVarWChar and see if that works. I am fairly sure this is a data type problem, but I am not at all sure of the answer with Sybase. You have a text data type so you need a text parameter, but which one?

Comment: I've tried that also but i will try it again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you gotten multiple parameters to work at all. I feel like it might have something to do with that.

Comment: Yes, I have now. As soon as I have time I will post the solution here.